# Stack Exchange wide gaming night?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, fun

## UPDATED - NEXT @20:00GMT 1st October

By posting this, I feel like this will become one of those Facebook parties where the entire house gets trashed... Crossing my fingers that it will not be like that!

Just for the fun of it, a few of us are trying to hold a gaming night - So far it looks like there are going to be quite a few people from Super User and Gaming Stack Exchange... but, everyone is welcome!

We are going to be playing **TF2**, and it will start at around 20:00 GMT on 1st October 2011 - It will run until people get bored!

It has a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/271/se-game-on) where you can discuss.

Hope to see you there!

All details are available in the Chat Room.

(sorry for late notice)

Comment: Seeing as you don't clarify, what is the *date* of this event? Is this happening right today?

Comment: @Grace Note - Feel like an idiot, it is tomorrow (updated post!) - there is an event and we say it a lot in the chat... it slipped my mind to post here.

Comment: I volunteer to help by playing an unrelated game in single-player mode.

Comment: @mmyers - spoil sport!... but funny +1 ... I hope if you are free, you will join in!

Comment: +1 Tempting. If everybody had decided to join up and help me take care of some deadlines here at the office, it would be much more fun ;)

Comment: I challenge you all to a deathmatch of Europa Universalis 3! *glares at everybody*

Comment: I'm going to play a round of Minesweeper in you guys' honour.

Comment: Why too localized? It is for everyone! ... And please no one close - we are planning on doing this weekly/monthly. It is pointless starting a new topic each time, I will simply edit this and change the dates.

Comment: How did I miss this!?! :(

Comment: @John - Don't worry, the next one won't be too far away. Monitor/favourite this thread and I will update the date next time there is an event.

Comment: Done.  However, I don't have an Nvidia or ATI card.  Is there another way to get the game?  Or maybe next game could be one that doesn't require an Nvidia or ATI card?

Comment: @John - Go in the chat room and ask - games and settings are all open for discussion. As for Nvidia or ATI, can you log on to steam from any computer with one (doesn't matter how old, doesn't need to run the game) - once activated, you can play the game on anything with the steam account.

Comment: @Jeff booo! Spoilsport. That was a worthy tag.

Answer (score 6):

We played for what, an hour and a half, and it was pretty good fun. HL2:DM is a horrible game but is easy to pick up. (plus an incredibly small download if you already have certain Source games - I thought I was going to miss it because I didn't already have the game half an hour before we started, but it was a 30MB download)

I may be a little biased though. Wil requested I posted the screenshots I had, to "encourage more people to play next time"

[scoreboard1](http://lts.cr/NHf)

[another scoreboard](http://lts.cr/NHj)
[another another](http://lts.cr/NHh)

[another another another](http://lts.cr/NHl)

[another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another another one.](http://lts.cr/NHd)

Comment: I'll update this sometime to record what we've done. Eventually.

Answer (score 5):

Wil didn't post the server info, but barring any changes before then:

Server: `hl2.ocrtf2.com:27015` / `206.217.135.94:27015` password: `stack`

Comment: ... :P They would see it when they come to our chat room! but +1... good!

Answer (score 3):

Be ready to be destroyed by the Almighty

[image]

## **KRONOS**!

Comment: Weren't so almighty when we were testing the server :P

Comment: It was a ruse my good UK friend! @Wil

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually played hl2:dm, but I play a ton of CS:S and I played through HL2, so I won't be entirely unschooled.  Looking forward to it if the schedule allows, but right now I think I can't make it unless you're still going like 7 hours later.

Comment: (I want to lie to pros as I know I will be rubbish, but can't!)... I did a survey and the majority of people wanted 6PM Uk time.... In chat, there were quite a few people wanting a later time slot. Feel free to go to the chat room and organise one yourself - the survey was awkward enough, so if you know a better way, give it a try! ... It is a community thing, got no problem with people doing/organising stuff themselves.

Comment: do you think you can make it this time?