# StackExchange Inbox always shows recurring chat event as "happening soon"

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

Whenever I display my Global Inbox, the top item is always a [recurring event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/271/se-game-on?tab=schedule) we have for the [StackExchange Game-On!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79027/stack-exchange-wide-gaming-night) event set for every 21 days.  It is also highlighted as if it were new if there are any other new items in the Global Inbox.

[image: My Global Inbox]

Comment: Been getting this for the past few days as well.

Comment: Annoying!!!!!!!15chars

Comment: As a side note, said event is next scheduled to happen on April 9th, so it's definitely not "starting soon."

Comment: Oh right, I meant to post this two days ago but never got around to it. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that; this was a combination of two bugs causing this (under pretty narrow conditions).

This shouldn't happen again, and those items should disappear from your inbox later today.